# ABAP ALV more fields values in subtotal line

Tags: abap

I have a simple question and I do not know if there is a solution.

I display an ALV to the user with subtotals by KUNNR. Now the user wants in the line of Subtotal and in the previous columns to display the values which are unique per customer.

```
| ACC  | RISK | KUNNR | PAYMENT | 
 ------------------------------- 
| 1010 |  05  |  186  |  32.50  |  
| 1010 |  05  |       |  33.50  |  
|      |      |  186  |  66.00  | <-- SUBTOTAL
```

What the user wants is:

```
| 1010 |  05  |  186  |  66.00  | <-- SUBTOTAL
```

The ACC and RISK are per customer.

Is there any way to do this?

**Addendum after József comment**: the SORTing table (for the ALV) is defined for the customer (KUNNR), I added the fields ACC and RISK to the sorting, but no values for ACC and RISK were displayed in the subtotal line.

Comment: I guess the SORTing table (for the ALV) is created for the customer (KUNNR) only. Add the fields ACC and RISK as well to the sorting!

Comment: I did it but no values for ACC & RISK in the subtotal line.

Comment: Change the ALV layout, that the sum line is shown above the items, strangely enough it solves the problem. Whether the user will like it...

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Summarize the data accordingly before handing to ALV perhaps